# How do I cascade delete polymorphic associations in active record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, rails-activerecord

Let's take this case as an example:

```
class Child < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :fruitful, polymorphic: true
end

class Parent < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :children, as: :fruitful, dependent: :destroy
end

# Once I create the parent and children
p = Parent.create
p.children << Child.new
p.children << Child.new
p.save

# But deleting parent does not delete children:
p.destroy  # why not?
```

The question becomes, is "dependent: :destroy" not supported with active record's polymorphic association and do I need to implement before_destroy callback to prevent orphaned records?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should that be `belongs_to :parent`?

You might just need to call `parent.reload` before calling `parent.destroy` so that it knows it's childrens id's. When you do `<< Child.new` the in memory object may not accurately reflect the data.

Edit: [This guy explains it better](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24174624/385532)!

In practice, I expect you would not normally be destroying an object directly after manipulating it's children, so this is likely a console issue and you shouldn't need to `reload` in your application.

Comment: Firstly, thanks for answering.  Secondly, this was a simplified example, where my real case is an actual model that has been populated with "children" using polymorphic association, and the destroy method was called within a "destroy" action of the controller.  I find that all NON-POLYMORFIC relationships are deleted from the DB, while polymorphic ones are retained.  I did notice that rails docs do NOT include "dependent: :destroy" option on such association...

Comment: Hah!  Appears I forgot to actually add dependent: :destroy in my code!

Answer (score 0):

If you need to delete the child and the parent too is to be deleted automatically

use the below

```
class Child < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :fruitful, polymorphic: true , dependent: :destroy
```

Answer (score 0):

Use destroy instead of delete

> :destroy, when the object is destroyed, destroy will be called on its
>   associated objects. :delete, when the object is destroyed, all its
>   associated objects will be deleted directly from the database without
>   calling their destroy method.